# HTML5 display table nested divs not working with Firefox & Opera

Tags: css, html, css-tables, tablerow

Have following testing code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="min-width:100%;min-height:100%;height:100%;width:100%">
<body style="margin:0;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;height:100%;width:100%">
<div style="display:table;width:100%;height:100%;min-wight:100%;min-height:100%;">
    <div style="display:table-row;background:red;">A</div>
    <div style="display:table-row;background:green;">
        <div style="display:block;background:yellow;width:100%;height:100%;">B</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row;background:blue;height:50px;">C</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox it displays yellow div small (as the table-row but is set display:block).
Opera too.
Chrome display yellow div in 100% height of green div (table-row).

I need this works in Firefox, Opera, IE>8 the same as in Chrome!

**UPDATE:**

I found following problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="min-width:100%;min-height:100%;height:100%;width:100%">
<body style="margin:0;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;height:100%;width:100%">
<div style="display:table;width:100%;height:100%;min-wight:100%;min-height:100%;">
    <div style="height:50px;display:table-row;background:red;">A</div>
    <div style="display:table-row;background:green;">
        <div style="display:table-cell;background:yellow;">
            <div style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;background:darkred;">B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row;background:blue;height:50px;">C</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Not working darkred div in Opera!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to make everything render consistently across IE, FireFox, and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="min-width:100%;min-height:100%;height:100%;width:100%">
<body style="margin:0;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;height:100%;width:100%">
<div style="display:table;width:100%;height:100%;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;">
    <div style="display:table-row;background:red;">
        <div style="display:table-cell">A</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row;background:green;">
        <div style="display:table-cell;background:yellow;width:100%;height:100%;">B</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row;background:blue;height:50px;">
        <div style="display:table-cell">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The only difference is I added `display:table-cell` divs within each table-row.  It will have a 50px tall "C" row, a minimal "A" row, and the rest filled with a yellow "B" row.

It looks like you can simply get away with just changing that inner "B" div from `display:block` to `display:table-cell`, but I think it's best practice to always have a `table-cell` within your `table-row` (I could be wrong?).

Screenshot of all 3 browsers with my modifications:

[image]

EDIT:

If you're trying to get your rows to have equal height, you can use this markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="min-width:100%;min-height:100%;height:100%;width:100%">
<body style="margin:0;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;height:100%;width:100%">
<div style="display:table;width:100%;height:100%;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;">
    <div style="display:table-row;background:red;height:33%">
        <div style="display:table-cell">A</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row;background:green;height:33%">
        <div style="display:table-cell;background:yellow;">B</div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-row;background:blue;height:33%;">
        <div style="display:table-cell">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Why red div have minimal height?

Comment: Look at my screenshots.  You don't have a height specified for the "A" row, and the yellow row has a height of 100% so it will take up all remaining space.  If you remove the letter "A" from the first row, the yellow will fill the remaining space and there won't be any red at all.

Comment: @AdamPlocher - There's nothing to require `display:table-cell` from a best practices point-of-view, CSS defines that a cell will be automatically generated as required. But it means that in its absence, the `display:block; height:100%' is 100% of the height of the generated cell. It seems that browser differ over how high this generated cell should be. Your solution, by explicitly setting the height of the cell, removes this ambiguity.

Comment: @Alohci thanks for the clarification.  I haven't used much of the display: table* stuff, that was just an assumption I made based on how the old table tags worked.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have equal heights for all rows, then it's better to use a proper table:

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <tr style="background:red;">
    <td>A</td></tr>
  <tr style="background:green;">
    <td style="background:yellow;">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:blue;">
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B5jUh/9/